# Update MongoDB object in object by id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Model:

```
const projectSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 50
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  },
  projectLead: {
    type: String
  },
  start: {
    type: String
  },
  end: {
    type: String
  },
  projectType: {
    type: String
  },
  claimId: {
    type: String
  },
  organization: {
    type: String
  },
  seats: [{
    id: String,
    employee: String,
    role: String,
    start: String,
    end: String,
    workload: Number,
    skills: Array,
    approved: Boolean
  }]
}, {
  timestamps: true
})
```

Model response example:

```
{
    "project": {
        "_id": "5cab4b9bc9b29a7ba2363875",
        "name": "Project Title",
        "description": "Project description",
        "projectLead": "email@email",
        "start": "2018-06-01T09:45:00.000Z",
        "end": "2019-06-31T09:45:00.000Z",
        "claimId": "AIIIIII",
        "organization": "Company ACE",
        "seats": [
            {
                "skills": [
                    "Node.js",
                    "Vue.js"
                ],
                "_id": "5cab548e5cefe27ef82ca313",
                "start": "2018-06-01T09:45:00.000Z",
                "end": "2019-06-31T09:45:00.000Z",
                "role": "Developer",
                "approved": false,
                "workload": 20,
                "employee": ''
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2019-04-08T13:24:43.253Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-04-08T14:02:54.257Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
exports.updateSeatEmployee = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const project = await Project.findOneAndUpdate({
      "seats._id": req.params.id
    }, {
      "seats.employee": req.body.employee
    }, {
      new: true
    })
    console.log("project", project);
    return res.json({
      project: project
    })
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
}
```

Debugger:

> Mongoose: users.createIndex({ email: 1 }, { unique: true, background:
>   true }) { sub: '5cab48ebec24577ab3329fcd', iat: 1554729210 }
>
> Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5cab48ebec24577ab3329fcd") },
>   { projection: {} })
>
> Mongoose: projects.findAndModify({ 'seats._id':
>   ObjectId("5cab529bcafa027e30ee229c") }, [], { '$setOnInsert': {
>   createdAt: new Date("Mon, 08 Apr 2019 14:45:56 GMT") }, '$set': {
>   'seats.$.employee': 'email@email.com', updatedAt: new
>   Date("Mon, 08 Apr 2019 14:45:56 GMT") } }, { new: true, upsert: false,
>   remove: false, projection: {} }) (node:33302) DeprecationWarning:
>   collection.findAndModify is deprecated. Use findOneAndUpdate,
>   findOneAndReplace or findOneAndDelete instead.
>
> project null

I want to search for a specific object in `seats` by its `id`.
This specific seat should be update. In my case I want to update the `employee` field.

If I do a `findOne({"seats._id": req.params.id})` I get the project back but `findOneAndUpdate` returns `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/index.html) since `seats` is an array and you should use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/index.html) operator if you want to update just one field

```
const project = await Project.findOneAndUpdate({
  "seats._id": req.params.id
}, {
  $set: { "seats.$.employee": req.body.employee }
}
```

Comment: @mrks have you tried both filtering conditions, like `{  _id: ObjectId("5cab48ebec24577ab3329fcd"), "seats._id": req.params.id }` ?